# using regex to find a string in a tag

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am editing a KML file that has info in it like:

```
        <name>some name</name>
        <description> some description and search target</description>
        <styleUrl>#icon-960-DB4436</styleUrl>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>
            34.7661563,32.059198,0
          </coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
```

I am trying to use a regex that will capture all the info from when  begins until  ends if some target string is present in the tag.

I tried this
`<placemark>.*?search target.*?</placemark>`

but ofcourse it will capture more than I need.

some help please?

Comment: Is your sample missing the opening `<Placemark>` tag? Are the tags really a mixture of case styles (some all lowercase, some leading caps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualify dot with a negative lookahead for `</Placemark>` to restrict searches to within such a tag.

To find the text `DB4436` (from your example) use:

```
<Placemark>((?!<\/Placemark>).)*DB4436((?!<\/Placemark>).)*<\/Placemark>
```

with the DOTALL flag on (you haven't indicated the language/tool you're using, so I can't show how to specify that - it varies).

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/ym8YH1eWZWE88f).

Comment: i'm using notepad++  and it works